# How can I hide messages of udev?

Tags: usb, udev

When I plug in a usbhub (7 sticks in) udev displays a lot of messages in console.
Can I hide these messages or send them to /dev/null?

Answer (score 10):

On CentOS, I don't get `udev` messages when I plug in a simple USB thumbstick. Instead I get:

```
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

a couple of times.

But this isn't `udev`, or `syslog` mentioning this to you on the console. You could know this for sure yourself, by killing `syslogd` or `rsyslogd` (Please make sure this isn't a production server, which I hope it is not what with inserting USB hubs and all that :) and re-inserting the USB device.

The messages still popup, so as [Ulrich](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/8979/ulrich-dangel) mentioned, this is coming from the kernel, or the USB module to be exact, which uses `kernel.printk` to show you these messages, not using any system services at all.

An excerpt from the linux documentation `sysctl/kernel.txt`:

> The four values in printk denote: console_loglevel,
>   default_message_loglevel, minimum_console_loglevel and
>   default_console_loglevel respectively.
>
> These values influence printk() behavior when printing or
>   logging error messages. See 'man 2 syslog' for more info on
>   the different loglevels.
>
> - console_loglevel: messages with a higher priority than
>     this will be printed to the console
> - default_message_level: messages without an explicit priority
>     will be printed with this priority
> - minimum_console_loglevel: minimum (highest) value to which
>     console_loglevel can be set
> - default_console_loglevel: default value for console_loglevel

```
    #define KERN_EMERG    "<0>"  /* system is unusable               */
    #define KERN_ALERT    "<1>"  /* action must be taken immediately */
    #define KERN_CRIT     "<2>"  /* critical conditions              */
    #define KERN_ERR      "<3>"  /* error conditions                 */
    #define KERN_WARNING  "<4>"  /* warning conditions               */
    #define KERN_NOTICE   "<5>"  /* normal but significant condition */
    #define KERN_INFO     "<6>"  /* informational                    */
    #define KERN_DEBUG    "<7>"  /* debug-level messages             */
```

So using the above mentioned values for arguments to printk, you can get the kernel to shut up about informational messages or simple warnings on the console. For example,

```
echo "3 3 3 3" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

made my insertions of the USB thumbstick go all quiet. Do you want to make it stick through a reboot, add a line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.printk = 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Since systemd v207 sysctl config files should be of the format `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by changing to a different syslog channel, provided you understand how syslog works:

From udev manual:

```
   udev_log
          The logging priority which can be set to err ,info or the corre-
          sponding numerical syslog(3) value.  The default value is err.
```

So now you could edit `/etc/udev/udev.conf` and change this value.

Comment: okay thanks for answering. How can I find out, which Syslog value I have to use that all usb-udev messages are hidden?

Comment: Do I have to use the the values of "Facility Level" or of "Severity Level"? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Facility_Levels

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try `sudo setterm --msg off`